# Firefox Loading bottom screen never stops

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to open something in Firefox with window.open() and when I load the window, the loading screen never stops. I still don't understand why. Please kindly advice.

**Screenshot**:
http://s3.postimg.org/eq0r6rr03/screenshot.png

**My Code:**

```
        var html = this.compilePageHtml(); //We get some HTML code
        this._previewWindow = window.open("about:blank", "PreviewWindow","width=320, height=570, scrollbars=yes" ); 
        this._previewWindow.document.write(html); //Loads HTML in new window popup
```

What is causing this issue? **On Chrome, Safari it works fine**

Thanks,
- R

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem is document.open(), I need to close document.close() in order for it to stop the transfer.

Comment: I've had this one too, `document.close` is what I did too.